# What is the definition of a homogenous vector field?

Tags: abstract-algebra, lie-groups

The question came about listening to online lectures ([here](https://youtu.be/mJ8ZDdA10GY?t=2646)) on the exponential map that allows projecting back to a manifold a pushed forward point via a linear operation on the tangent space. OK, something like that - way over my head!

At some point the idea of left-invariant vector fields is brought up as essential to the construct. There would be some group operation on the Lie group that would somehow be associated to a pushforward of the vector field. Again, probably more wrong than right, but to give some idea to the expert reader of the material I'm referring to.

> "We are not interested in any vector field on a Lie group. We are only interested in a special class of vector fields: namely, those vector fields that if I push them forward, and I look at the result, the result doesn't look different from the vector field I started from. For instance, in the plane, $\mathbb R^2$ with addition is a Lie group. Now, if I take a **homogeneous vector field** and you do an addition, you push forward the vectors of this vector field by this addition. Intuitively, you push the vector field on this or that direction, and since it is a homogenous vector field, after pushing, it will look the same. So the **homogeneous vector field** in $\mathbb R^2,$ equipped with addition, making it a Lie group, is a vector field that under left translations, or, rather the induced-pushforward of left translations stays the same."

The equation on the blackboard I think means that a linear pushforward of vector in a vector field by an element $g\in M$ of the Lie group is defined as the pushforward induced in each vector in the group:

$(l_{g*}X)_{gh}:= l_{g*}(X_h)$ with $X$ being a vector field on the Lie group, and $X_h$ a given vector in $T_hG.$

Further, the left invariance is defined as fulfilling

$l_{g*}X = X$

---

The question comes about with a comment about the pushforward in this setting, somehow, moving forward a vector field without really changing it, and the thought of a "homogeneous vector field" that is translated comes up as an intuition.

Searching for "homogeneous vector fields" there are some very hairy results that assume the definition is well understood. Unfortunately, I can't find an introductory level definition.

I see, for instance, that if the vector field spirals, the action of an element (a vector) on all the others under addition, will not result in a vector field resembling the original one at all. But **is then "homogeneous" connected to the idea of zero curl and zero divergence**, for instance?

---

I found the answer [here](https://www.math.usm.edu/schroeder/books/vector%20field%20intro.pdf). Very straightforward and anticlimactic: A homogeneous vector field is a vector field that has the same value at every point. Like this:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Homegenous here means "left invariant", in $\mathbb{R} ^{2}$ think of  "tranlating" a fixed vector at the origin all around,so it's the closest thing to being "constant", but one need to be careful here, since these vectors live in different tangent spaces.
in general if G is a lie group, then every element g of G defines a Diffeomorphism called "left translation" $L_g:G\mapsto G$, $L_g(x) =gx$, $L_{g} (e) =g$, so its differential induces a linear isomorphism between the tangent space at the identity and the tangent space at $g$, so we can mimic the same construction done in the plane by starting with an arbitrary vector at the origin, and then "pushing" it forward using the differential of left translations. The resulting vector field is said to be left invariant ( homogenous is used instead by the source u are refering to).

Comment: I see that if all the vectors in the field point in the same direction, the action of an element under vector addition will just translate the field, whereas if there is some curl, that won't be the case. So is the idea behind 'homogeneous' zero curl, for instance?